# Displaying text in textarea with formatting in place (e.g. <br>)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I display a wall of text example:

```
hello
<br>
how is your day
<br>
123
```

Into

```
hello

how is your day

123
```

I'm trying to display these into a textarea field as well.

I've tried with this
`$('<textarea />').html(theString).text();` but it does not display my desired result

Edit:

Current code:

```
function displayCustom (data) {
var myString= data.getAttribute("data-contentDetails");
$('#textareaContent").html(myString);
}
```

Comment: First of clear me, how you are saving such kind of text ? Is this you are saving using PHP ?

Comment: @JohnDoe its in a file which i parsed into as a json format and save in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not possible to do this with textarea. you can use `content editable` div

```js
var theString = `Hello.<br>Hi.<br>Hey, <strong>user</strong> <span style="color: red">Logout</span>.`

// in pure js
document.getElementById('textareaContent').innerHTML = theString;

// OR in jQuery
$('#textareaContent').html(theString)
```

```css
div {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="textareaContent" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

## UPDATE

if you have to use textarea and just need to use `<br />` (you couldn't use another HTML tag as a text) you can use:

```js
var myString = `Hello<br>Hi<br>Hey, use`

$('#text').html(myString.replace(/<br>/g, '\n'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: I've tried on my end and it' not working as expected. Would there be any difference because my string being retrieved from the data attribute.
My current code is 

`var myString = data.getAttribute("data-contentDetails")`
`$('#textareaContent)".html(myString)`

Comment: @plzSOS could you try to set the div id to `textareaContent`? like `<div id="textareaContent" contenteditable="true"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Use a Div with a contenteditable attribute if you want the user to edit the displayed new format. Try to append or insert this.

For a textarea

```
$('<div contenteditable="true" />').html(theString);
```

Just remove the `contendeditable="true"` attribute if you just want to display the new format.

Comment: I've tried on my end and it' not working as expected. Would there be any difference because my string being retrieved from the data attribute.
My current code is 

`var myString = data.getAttribute("data-contentDetails")`
`$('#textareaContent)".html(myString)`